# NPM not recognised, unable to install Bower (ultimately want to work with Polymer's "Material" for app development)

Tags: android, github, npm, material-design, bower-install

I'm really sorry for such a newbie question, but I've been looking through similar questions on here, and nobody seems to be getting the same error messages as myself - plus, often the questions go on a tangent too dissimilar to what I'm trying to achieve, & I end up with my head spinning in circles.

Basically, I want to work with the Polymer Project's "Material", for the purpose of practicing simple App development; however, after successfully installing npm (via Node JS), & Git, I am unable to execute even the most simple first command of

npm install -g bower

This is totally doing my head in, it seems so stupid to be unable even to install Bower.  Of course, Bower is needed in order to install Polymer's Material.  Am I missing something?  Have I misunderstood the way in which these operations are to be carried out?

When typing in the above, all I get is:

"NPM is not recogised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Any help will be much appreciated.  NB - I'll ensure that future questions are asked in the correct format (with the quotes & whatnot), but for now, pleeeease, someone tell me how to crack this nut, so I can at least get started with the programming shenanigans.

Thanks,

Simon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add NodeJS to your Path variable.

Got to Environment Variables on the System Properties and add:

```
;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

to the end of your Path variable.

After that, reopen your prompt and try npm again.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that now.  I was just following the basic instructions laid out on each site about what to install, I hadn't realised there was an extra step involved.

Comment: Hi again, 

Yeah, for some reason that had no effect. I copied exactly what you wrote, but nothing.